# Symfony2 can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.50' (113)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, centos, mariadb

I have remote mysql server @192.168.1.50.
I can access it through [http://192.168.1.50/phpmyadmin/] on my pc,
or by using

```
ssh root@192.168.1.50
```

But in Symfony2 when I run

```
 php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force  gives me error

[PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.50' (113  
 )
```

my parameter.yml

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 192.168.1.50
database_port: 3306
database_name: xxhealthdb
database_user: kproduction
database_password: xxroot
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I think there must be some thing wrong in this file or may be anything else from which I am unaware. Please help me

Note: I am using MariaDB and CentOS for remote server and Ubuntu for my(client) PC.

my log details

```
      2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener    "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
 [2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
  [2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
   [2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
    [2015-01-31 17:35:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've running MariaDB server and Symfony2 is trying to connect MySql server. Try to install MySQL server for centos7 and configure the MySql config file found under /etc/my.cfg.

Make sure [mysql] which is your server and [client] is allowing connection from default port 3306.

Make sure your centos firewall is allowing TCP public connection on 3306.

After configuring above changes restart your MySQL server and try again, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

By default, The database server doesn't allow connections from the user apps. 
It might be a misconfiguration from your DB Server.

Try to attach the logs here so i can help you further.

Symfony2 Logs can be found in the : /app/logs directory.

Good luck!

Comment: pls see my log details

Comment: @AnishShah Those aren't the full logs though? there's no error or warning in them.

Comment: These are the only logs generated in my dev log file

Comment: Then i guess you should start your manual troubleshooting. As i mentioned before, check the config on your Db server, check for remote access permissions on your database

Comment: if there is any remote server permition issue then i might not able to use ssh and access remote database but i can do that

Comment: App permissions are different then regular access permissions.

try to remove or comment out 'skip-networking' in mysql.ini

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add your IP in allow remote access? It might be one of the reason.

Comment: Log into control panel of your server and look for something called allow remote access to database

Comment: i put allow all...in php config file

Comment: Perhaps this might help. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/ you might want to contact your hosting company to help you if you are stuck